# Why redis cluster only supports database 0

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

As per the docs, https://redis.io/commands/select,

> When using Redis Cluster, the SELECT command cannot be used, since Redis Cluster only supports database zero. In the case of a Redis Cluster, having multiple databases would be useless and an unnecessary source of complexity.